# How to post client facebook ad by facebook ad api?

Tags: c#, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I have been working in Facebook ad API. I am able to create abs in sandbox mode as well live mode. Our application is approved. I am getting a strange issue when I try to create ad for my facebook pages its created but when any other user tries to create ad its giving error message like

> "{"error":{"message":"Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'act_facebookadaccountid' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,"error_subcode":33,"fbtrace_id":"B27E15+gMhB"}}"

We have taken following permission

- business_management
- manage_pages
- Ads Management
- Basic Access

My main aim is my customer can connect with our app they can select page for whom they want to run ad and create ad using our app.

Please help me to sort out this

Comment: @adiga do you have answer ?

Comment: no. Just cleaning up the formatting

Comment: OK Thanks @adiga

Answer (score 0):

This may have to do with your access level? You need Standard access so any ad account may be used. Otherwise you are limited to the max. 25 ad accounts you specify in the Ads API account configuration tool.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access/#limits